# terraform destroy produces cycle error when no cycles present

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

#### Terraform Version

```
Terraform v0.12.1
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

`main.tf` in my root provider:

```
provider "google" {}

module "organisation_info" {
  source           = "../../modules/organisation-info"
  top_level_domain = "smoothteam.fi"
  region           = "us-central1"
}

module "stack_info" {
  source            = "../../modules/stack-info"
  organisation_info = "${module.organisation_info}"
}
```

Here's module 'organisation-info':

```
variable "top_level_domain" {}
variable "region" {}

data "google_organization" "organization" {
  domain = "${var.top_level_domain}"
}

locals {
  organization_id    = "${data.google_organization.organization.id}"
  ns = "${replace("${var.top_level_domain}", ".", "-")}-"
}

output "organization_id" {
  value = "${local.organization_id}"
}

output "ns" {
  value = "${local.ns}"
}
```

Then module 'stack-info':

```
variable "organisation_info" {
  type        = any
  description = "The organisation-scope this environment exists in."
}

module "project_info" {
  source            = "../project-info"
  organisation_info = "${var.organisation_info}"
  name              = "${local.project}"
}

locals {
  # Use the 'default' workspace for the 'staging' stack.
  name = "${terraform.workspace == "default" ? "staging" : terraform.workspace}"
  # In the 'production' stack, target the production project. Otherwise, target the staging project.
  project = "${local.name == "production" ? "production" : "staging"}"
}

output "project" {
  value = "${module.project_info}" # COMMENTING THIS OUTPUT REMOVES THE CYCLE.
}
```

And finally, the 'project-info' module:

```
variable "organisation_info" {
  type        = any
}
variable "name" {}

data "google_project" "project" {
  project_id = "${local.project_id}"
}

locals {
  project_id = "${var.organisation_info.ns}${var.name}"
}

output "org" {
  value = "${var.organisation_info}"
}
```

#### Debug Output

After doing `terraform destroy -auto-approve`, I get:

```
Error: Cycle: module.stack_info.module.project_info.local.project_id, module.stack_info.output.project, module.stack_info.module.project_info.data.google_project.project (destroy), module.organisation_info.data.google_organization.organization (destroy), module.stack_info.var.organisation_info, module.stack_info.module.project_info.var.organisation_info, module.stack_info.module.project_info.output.org
```

And `terraform graph -verbose -draw-cycles -type=plan-destroy` gives me this graph:
[image]
Source:

```
digraph {
        compound = "true"
        newrank = "true"
        subgraph "root" {
                "[root] module.organisation_info.data.google_organization.organization" [label = "module.organisation_info.data.google_organization.organization", shape = "box"]
                "[root] module.stack_info.module.project_info.data.google_project.project" [label = "module.stack_info.module.project_info.data.google_project.project", shape = "box"]
                "[root] provider.google" [label = "provider.google", shape = "diamond"]
                "[root] module.organisation_info.data.google_organization.organization" -> "[root] module.stack_info.module.project_info.data.google_project.project"
                "[root] module.organisation_info.data.google_organization.organization" -> "[root] provider.google"
                "[root] module.stack_info.module.project_info.data.google_project.project" -> "[root] provider.google"
        }
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

The idea is to use modules at the org, project and stack levels to set up naming conventions that can be re-used across all resources. Organisation-info loads organisation info, project-info about projects, and stack-info determines which project to target based on current workspace.

I have omitted a bunch of other logic in the modules in order to keep them clean for this issue.

According to `terraform` there are no cycles, and `destroy` should work fine.

#### Actual Behavior

We get the cycle I posted above, even though terraform shows no cycles.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Set up the three modules, `organisation-info`, `project-info`, and `stack-info` as shown above.
2. Set up a root provider as shown above.
3. `terraform init`
4. `terraform destroy` (it doesn't seem to matter if you've applied first)

#### Additional Context

The weird thing is that if I comment out this output in `stack-info`, the cycle stops:

```
output "project" {
  value = "${module.project_info}" # IT'S THIS... COMMENTING THIS OUT REMOVES THE CYCLE.
}
```

This seems really weird... I neither understand why outputting a variable should make a difference, nor why I'm getting a cycle error when there's no cycle.

Oddly, `terraform plan -destroy` does not reveal the cycle, only `terraform destroy`.

My spidey sense tells me evil is afoot.

Appreciate anyone who can tell me what's going on, whether this is a bug, and perhaps how to work around.

Comment: I'm having something similar, same version. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548780/terraform-cycle-when-altering-a-count

Comment: I'm discussing this with the dudes at Hashicorp, feel free to chime in and describe your experience. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21662

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow that.

Comment: same issue. I upgraded to Terraform v0.13.2.. but still same issue `Error: Cycle: ....destroy deposed` :(

Comment: Any follow up on this issue? This is happening to us constantly. Sometimes just re-running it causes it to no longer have the cycle. Its killing me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same cycle error was because the out of 3 key:pair one of the key:pair expected by map type variable inside variables.tf of a module not declared in main.tf nor in anywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example and how to fix the situation?