# Terraform cycle when altering a count

Tags: terraform

I have some resources whose `count` is parameterised by a variable. This is used to create VM resources as well as `null_resource`s for e.g. running deployment scripts on them. When I reduce the value of the count from 2 to 1 and apply, I get an error.

Terraform executes `plan` with no complaints. But when I `apply`, it tells me there is a cycle:

> Error: Cycle: null_resource.network_connection_configuration[7] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[8] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[3] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[4] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[0] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[6] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[1] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[9] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[2] (destroy), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[10] (destroy), hcloud_server.kafka[2] (destroy), local.all_machine_ips, null_resource.network_connection_configuration (prepare state), null_resource.network_connection_configuration[5] (destroy)

Here is the relevant part of the file:

```
variable kafka_count {
  default = 3
}

resource "hcloud_server" "kafka" {
  count       = "${var.kafka_count}"
  name        = "kafka-${count.index}"
  image       = "ubuntu-18.04"
  server_type = "cx21"
}

locals {
  all_machine_ips = "${hcloud_server.kafka.*.ipv4_address)}"
}

resource "null_resource" "network_connection_configuration" {
  count = "${length(local.all_machine_ips)}"

  triggers = {
    ips = "${join(",", local.all_machine_ips)}"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "hcloud_server.kafka"
  ]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "deploy"
    host        = "${element(local.all_machine_ips, count.index)}"
    port        = 22
  }

// ... some file provisioners
}
```

When I try to find the cycle using the visualisation:

```
terraform graph -verbose -draw-cycles
```

There are no cycles visible.

When I use `TF_LOG=1` the debug log doesn't show any errors

So the issue is that I can increase the count but not decrease it. I don't want to manally hack the file as it means I won't be able to scale down in future! I'm using Terraform v0.12.1.

Are there any strategies for debugging this situation?

Comment: Note that even though you are not explicitly specifying a `depends_on`, you can still pick up implicit dependencies when you map outputs from one resource or data as an input to another resource. Also you could post a MCVE for this since the error message only references two resources.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to mention that but didn't want to make the question too long. I can add it, but if I add all the dependencies of those items I'll end up with basically the same file. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: With this level of information `null_resource.files_sync` looks like the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. The problem is it's all so coupled that removing that requires the removal of a lot of other null_resources. At that point so much has changed that I need to set up a whole new project with real VMs to test out if the MVCE still applies. If the error was detected in `plan` this would be a lot eaiser!

Comment: I'm afraid I took the cowardly way out and commented out the `null_resources` to let them get destroyed (which is safe because they don't really exist). With those not existing I can safely change the count to scale down the 'real' resources. Not satisfactory, but I have a suspicion that it could be connected to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21662 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514719/terraform-destroy-produces-cycle-error-when-no-cycles-present#comment99679490_56514719

Comment: @MattSchuchard After some refactoring to simplify dependencies I've arrived ... back in the same place. So example included now. This really does look like a bug!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with 0.12.x - I was calling a provisioner within an `aws_instance` resource, which was giving the same error you had when increasing the count for the resource.

I got around it by using the self object (`self.private_ip`) to reference the resource rather than using count.index or element().